# Update iframe src based on input value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an iframe change based on a text input field.

The string that I want to append to the url that the user will input is in the middle of the url though.

Have tried but not quite sure how to define it correctly

```
<script>

$("#search").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 var url = "http://www2.sdfsdf.com/admin/agent_order_srch_ordet.asp?action=searchStrPostcode&idOrder=" $('#search').val(); "&Submit=Search";
        $("#someFrame").attr("src", url;
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a copy paste error inside your url variable. Here's the corrected version. And I used the plain javascript version to change the url.

```
<script>

$("#search").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "http://www2.sdfsdf.com/admin/agent_order_srch_ordet.asp?action=searchStrPostcode&idOrder=" + $('#search').val() + "&Submit=Search";
    $("#someFrame").get(0).src = url;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this I have tried it but it does not update the iframe. I can see it adding src in firebug but it is empty.

Comment: Hi there it was my fault. Had wrong id's that stopped it working. Its fine now. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#search").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "http://www2.sdfsdf.com/admin/agent_order_srch_ordet.asp?action=searchStrPostcode&idOrder=" + $(this).val() + "&Submit=Search";
    $("#someFrame").attr("src", url);
})
```

Note the `+` character is used to concatenate string values together.